# How do I prevent QListView in QGraphicsScene from drawing outside scroll area when scaling with QT_SCALE_FACTOR

Tags: c++, qt

When I display a QListWidget or QListView in a QGraphicsScene the text for each item is drawn outside of the widget boundaries if scroll bars are necessary.  This only occurs when I use QT_SCALE_FACTOR to scale the application.  Is there a way to prevent the list widget/list view items from being displayed outside the scroll area without explicitly setting a width for the items?  If I set the width I lose some of the text.  I have also tried setting the GraphicsItemFlag QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape.  This keeps the overhang restricted to the width of the outer widget but I want to prevent overhang entirely.

QListWidget in QGraphicsScene

[image]

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(w);
lw = new QListWidget();
l->addWidget(lw);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pw = scene()->addWidget(w);
pw->resize(200,300);

for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    QListWidgetItem *litem = new QListWidgetItem("Text text text text   text text text");
    lw->insertItem(0, litem);
}
```

Comment: This is a long shot but there's loosely similar Qt issue reported and its workaround would be change QGraphicsProxyWidget cache mode;  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63668?focusedCommentId=374042&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-374042 (worth trying at least).

Comment: Setting the cache mode to QGraphicsItem::DeviceCoordinateCache does keep the text inside the scroll area but it makes the text a little blurry and more difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cache mode to QGraphicsItem::DeviceCoordinateCache prevents the listview/listwidget text from displaying outside the boundaries of the widget.  The text does become a little blurry but the user can still read it.  Thank you harism for your response!

```
pw->setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::DeviceCoordinateCache);
```